# Capturing URL parameters after hashtag with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, url-parameters

I'm trying to capture the URL parameters from the following URL with Sinatra: `http://localhost:4567/token#access_token=7nuf5lgupiya8fd6rz4yzkzvwwo2ria&scope=user_read`

I'm tried using a couple code blocks to do this:

```
get '/token' do
    puts params['access_token']
end
```

and

```
get '/:token' do |token|
    puts token
end
```

and

```
get '/token#:token' do |token|
    puts token
end
```

However none of these work.  In the first block I get an empty string, in the second block I get the string `"token"`, and in the third block I get "Sinatra doesn't know this ditty".

What would be the appopriate solution in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that url you wrote correct? I think it needs to be

`http://localhost:4567/token?access_token=7nuf5lgupiya8fd6rz4yzkzvwwo2ria&scope=user_read`

With a `?` instead of a `#` after `/token`. With that change, you should be able to access all the query parameters in the `params` hash.

Comment: Yep the URL is correct.  I'm authenticating with Twitch.tv and I set the redirect URI to http://localhost:4567

Comment: Hm yeah I see that format in the twitch api documentation. Weird! That's not a standard way to send query parameters. Lemme dig deeper.

Comment: From the twitch API documentation: "Note that the access token is in the URL fragment, not the query string, so it won't show up in HTTP requests to your server. URL fragments can be accessed from JavaScript with document.location.hash." Looks like you're gonna have to write some Javascript :)

Comment: Ah ok interesting. So it looks like I'll have to use the authorization code flow in order for me to make calls with the server.